# Including CSS into my nodejs project

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, routes

I realize questions of this type have been posted quite a few times, but after looking around for a bit I haven't managed to find one that works for my setup.

I'm trying to load my CSS file into my html page. My project's client-side structure looks like this:

```
public    
  |  css
  |  js
  |  lib
  |  views
```

My html file is in the views directory, and has this CSS tag in it:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/client.css">
```

My router isn't catching the CSS file at all, I suspect because the CSS is using **href** and not **src** to request the file.

In my app.js configuration file, I have this line of code, which honestly I'm not sure as to the meaning of:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + 'public/views');
```

My goal is to setup my project so that it will load the CSS files into the browser. I can do most of the client-side and server-side coding, but setting up this bit of routing always gets me :(   Any advice?

PS - Please redirect me to better questions that have already been answered if one is found. I'm going to continue looking for an answer as well.

Comment: Note that paths like `href="css/client.css"` will be treated as relative to the current page's address (i.e. `window.location.pathname`). You can add a `/` prefix, as `href="/css/client.css"`, to instead have them relative to the root of the domain.

Comment: Does your application make `.use()` of [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve files under `public/`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski What does it mean to be relative to the root of the domain? Also, I have tried a few different combinations of app.set() and app.use(express.static(...)) but I don't really understand how they work. What I am really looking for at this point is a working example of how this should work

Comment: Or, relative to the host/hostname. For example, if the page is at `http://localhost:3000/foo/1/bar`, using the `/` prefix will ignore everything after the host, `/foo/1/bar`, roughly using `"http://localhost:3000" + "/css/client.css"`. Compared to without the `/`, which only ignores the "filename," `bar` – `"http://localhost:3000/foo/1/" + "css/client.css"`.

Comment: why don't use the express static server middleware? add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` to your start file;